# Input string was not in a correct format - URI 1116

Tags: c#

I have a problem in my code that I can't solve:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

I can't run it on a platform's online compiler, which is exactly where I need to use it.

```
using System;

public class help {
    public static void Main() {
        int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            string[] line = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            double X = double.Parse(line[0]);
            double Y = double.Parse(line[1]);
            if (Y == 0) {
                Console.WriteLine("divisao impossivel");
            } else {
                double divisao = X / Y; // Digite aqui o calculo da divisao
                Console.WriteLine(divisao.ToString("F1"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state where the error occurred. Error `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format` occurs if one enters a non-integer character and then try to parse it as an integer, likewise with double. Use `TryParse` instead.

Your program doesn't provide any instructions, so it isn't apparent what one should enter.

Try the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome. This program will divide two double values and display the result.");
    Console.WriteLine("To exit the program, type 'exit'\n");

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Enter two double values, seperated by a space (ex: 2.2 10.4) or type 'exit' to quit the program. : ");

        string line = Console.ReadLine();

        if (line.ToLower().Trim() == "exit" || line.ToLower().Trim() == "quit")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nExiting. Hope you enjoyed using the program.");
            break; //exit loop
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
        {
            double X = 0;
            double Y = 0;

            //trim leading and trailing spaces, then split on space
            string[] userInputArr = line.Trim().Split(' ');

            if (userInputArr != null && userInputArr.Length == 2)
            {
                //try to parse user input
                Double.TryParse(userInputArr[0], out X);
                Double.TryParse(userInputArr[1], out Y);

                if (Y == 0)
                {
                    //dividing by 0 is not allowed
                    Console.WriteLine("divisao impossivel");
                    continue; //go to next iteration
                }

                double divisao = X / Y; // Digite aqui o calculo da divisao
                Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + divisao.ToString("F1") + "\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError: Invalid input. Please try again.");
            }
        }

    } while (true);
}
```

**Note**: The above also works if one uses a ',' instead of '.' for double values using a "en-US" keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a different language, you will need to provide the `CultureInfo` as well.

```
// using System.Globalization;

Console.WriteLine(divisao.ToString("F1", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-PT")));
```

I believe the portuguese language uses `,` instead of `.` that is used in the english language. To force portuguese decimal representation to string, you have to define the CultureInfo.